# Why is this parallel code slower than its similar non parallel version?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I have the following code (copied here from LINQPad). Obviously it looks like I am not understanding how TPL works or the code is garbage, why does the parallel version run slower than its non-parallel counterpart?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ParallelOptions ops = new ParallelOptions();
    ops.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;

    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel.ForEach<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000), ops, x => { int y = x + 1; });
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Parallel: {0}", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000))
    {
        int y = x + 1;
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Non-parallel: {0}\n", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

First 10 results:

Parallel: 0.1991644
Non-parallel: 0.0466178

Parallel: 0.1723428
Non-parallel: 0.0447134

Parallel: 0.1141791
Non-parallel: 0.0444557

Parallel: 0.1758878
Non-parallel: 0.0444636

Parallel: 0.1687637
Non-parallel: 0.0444338

Parallel: 0.1677679
Non-parallel: 0.0445771

Parallel: 0.1191462
Non-parallel: 0.0446116

Parallel: 0.1702483
Non-parallel: 0.0454863

Parallel: 0.1143605
Non-parallel: 0.0451731

Parallel: 0.2155218
Non-parallel: 0.0450392

Comment: starting up threads is not without a cost

Comment: Debug mode compilation? Since when optimized the code does nothing and might be optimized away even. No point in determining which is faster: doing nothing or starting threads to do nothing.

Comment: Threads are incredibly expensive; it only makes sense to hire workers when you have *huge* amounts of work for them to do.

Comment: look at the accepted answer on this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031820/when-to-use-partitioner-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the best answer you can get is to run a profiler tool and measure what is going on with your code. But my educated guess is that your parallel code is slower because your code is so simple that starting up threads and switching between them add up so much cost that any advantage in the calculation speed is negligible.

But try to make some substantial computations and you eventually will have the parallel execution advantage. Your code is too simple. Modern CPUs are not to be loaded in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot add this as a comment, I am adding another answer to post the modified code. What @ixSci said in his answer seems to be correct. I was performing a trivial operation in the parallel code body that was executing really fast but the slowness came from the fact that a lot of time was spent on context switching between threads? When I changed the code to sleep for some time instead of increasing the int value by 1, the parallel code was roughly 4 (no. of cores in my CPU) times faster than the non parallel version.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ParallelOptions ops = new ParallelOptions();
    ops.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;

    var partitioner = Partitioner.Create<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5000));

    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel.ForEach<int>(partitioner, ops, x => { Thread.Sleep(1); });
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Parallel: {0}", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(1, 5000))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Non-parallel: {0}\n", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

First 10 results:

Parallel: 1.2887589
Non-parallel: 5.0020569

Parallel: 1.277047
Non-parallel: 5.0011116

Parallel: 1.2790631
Non-parallel: 5.0001498

Parallel: 1.2770644
Non-parallel: 5.0052016

Parallel: 1.2770013
Non-parallel: 5.0021479

Parallel: 1.2770031
Non-parallel: 5.0001927

Parallel: 1.2799937
Non-parallel: 5.0062141

Parallel: 1.2819909
Non-parallel: 5.0171945

Parallel: 1.2780496
Non-parallel: 5.0071667

Parallel: 1.2821714
Non-parallel: 5.0082108

Parallel: 1.2777875
Non-parallel: 5.0152099

Comment: This is also not a good example. If you and the `ThreadPool` stop limiting the number of threads used (by not forcing `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to be `ProcessorCount` and by adding something like `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 4);`), then you're going to get a speedup that's much more than the number of CPU cores.