# Using LINQ how to split string (not on character but on index)

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I wanted to split a string

Input :

```
ABCDEFGHI
```

Output :

```
ABC, DEF, GHI
```

One way is by using For Loop.

```
string str = "ABCDEFGHI";

List<string> lst = new List<string>();

string temp = "";

for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    temp = str[i].Tostring();

    if((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        lst.Add(temp);
        temp = "";
    }
}

string final_str = string.Join(", ", lst);
```

But how to do that using `LINQ`?

Comment: Lots of options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396048/c-sharp-elegant-way-of-partitioning-a-list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And another one (*without* [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)):

```
var str = "ABCDEFGHI";
var tmp = str.Select((i, index) => new { i, index })
             .GroupBy(g => g.index / 3, e => e.i)
             .Select(g => String.Join("", g));
var final_string = String.Join(", ", tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "ABCDEFGHI";

var result = testStr.Select(s => testStr.IndexOf(s))
                   .Where(i => i%3 == 0)
                   .Select(i => testStr.Substring(i,3))
                   .Aggregate("", (a,s) => a += s + ",");
```

Comment: won't work if any character occurs more than once in the string

Comment: harsh to downvote for that, given that the example string was very specific.

Comment: mmh, OK. You're right about the example string beeing very specific and not very clear; I removed the downvote. But the code Nikhil provided would work on other strings, and yours not.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

```
List<string> lst = str.Batch(3).Select(s => String.Join("",s)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

using [MoreLinq.Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs)

```
var result = str.Batch(3);
```

type of result is IEnumerable>, ToArray can be used to make it IEnumerable< char[] >

**EDIT** I forgot last join statement in the first glance

```
var finalStr = String.Join(",",str.Batch(3).Select(x=>new String(x.ToArray())))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String.Join("", str.Select((x, i) => (i + 1)%3 == 0 ? x + " " : x.ToString()))
```

Comment: won't work since this adds an additional comma add the end of the string if the length of the string is divisible by three.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't even see the comma. :) It can of course be trimmed which will make this call shorther than your version.