# How to convert the specific law of one-dimensional array into two-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, dimensions

Like this

```
string[]  strarry = [12, 34, A1, FE, 12, 34, EA, 0, FE]
```

`12` is the beginning ,
`FE` is the end,
Turn into

```
string strarry = [[12,34,A1,FE], [12,34,EA,0,FE]];
```

The *distance* from `12` to `FE` is not necessarily *fixed* (`4`)

How can I do it? Thank you

Comment: And what have you tried, what is the problem?

Comment: "The length from 12 to Fe is not necessarily"... is not necessarily what? What is the criterium for dividing the area? Is the length of `strarry` always the same (9 elements)? And you always want to have 4 elements in the first subarray and 5 in the second?

Comment: When you say "two-bit" array, you presumably mean two-dimensional array, right?

Comment: Is two-dimensional array;God,Is my fault

Comment: beginning is 12; ending is FE .There are not necessarily Four units; sorry :(

Comment: You can take a look at how to partition a list, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396143/1817574. Converting the result to a 2D array should not be hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you right (you want to obtain *jagged array* `string[][]` from *ordinal* one - `string[]`), you can try *Linq* in order to `GroupBy` items into subarrays:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string[] strarry = new string[]
    {"12", "34", "A1", "FE", "12", "34", "EA", "0", "FE"};

  // Here we exploit side effects, be careful with them
  int groupIndex = 0;

  string[][] result = strarry
    .GroupBy(value => value == "FE" ? groupIndex++ : groupIndex)
    .Select(group => group.ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Let's have a look:

```
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(line => "[" + string.Join(", ", line) + "]"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
[12, 34, A1, FE]
[12, 34, EA, 0, FE]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how applyable this code is for you, but maybe it gets you somewhere. Best of luck!

```
        var strarry = "12, 34, A1, FE, 12, 34, EA, 0, FE";
        var splittedArrays = strarry.Split(", FE", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < splittedArrays.Length; i++)
        {
            if (splittedArrays[i][0].Equals(','))
            {
                splittedArrays[i] = splittedArrays[i].Substring(2);
            }

            splittedArrays[i] += ", FE";
            Console.WriteLine(splittedArrays[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I want to change from 1D array to 2D array,Your answer made me fruitful